# 'type' is not a member type of 'T'

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Getting compiler error on declaration: `type: T.type`:

> 'type' is not a member type of 'T'

```
public class ParseRealmSync {

    public static func synchronize <T: Model> (type: T.type){
        var allObjects = [type]()
        var limit = 0
        var skip = 0
        var query = PFQuery(className: T.parseClassName(), predicate: nil)
        query.limit = limit
        query.skip = skip

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            println(objects)
        }
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: Do you need to have the type passed as parameter? Can't you just `var allObjects = [T]()` ?

Comment: @libec I believe if I'll not pass ```type: T.type``` as a parameter, then function will have no idea about this type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `T.Type` instead of `T.type`.

Also

```
var allObjects: [T] = []
```

instead of

```
var allObjects = [type]()
```